# tar folder in s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tar

Let's say I have a folder on s3:

```
s3://tmp/folder1
```

With several folders within. I would like this to now be:

```
s3://tmp/folder1.tar.gz
```

in which the contents of folder1 have been tar.gz'd. However, from what I can find, the only way to do this would be to:

1. Either download folder1 to a local directory or cp/mv to an existing ec2 instance,
2. run tar czv folder1.tar.gz folder1
3. Reupload to s3://tmp

Is there a way to do this *without* having to move/download folder1? In other words, is there an amazon cli command / set of commands to do this without the download / moving?

Answer (score 5):

No.

Amazon S3 does not provide the ability to manipulate the contents of objects.

You would need to copy the data *somewhere*, run the `tar` command, then upload it.

Think of it like asking a Hard Disk to tar/zip a file without a computer attached. It doesn't know how to do that.